# How to reset EditForm's DataAnnotationsValidator in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-blazor

How can I reset the validations of my model that is inside `EditForm` with `DataAnnotationsValidator` ?

My problem is that I have a form in a modal, once the user closes and opens the modal again, all the fields still have the validations error message. I want to remove the error messages when the user closes the modal.

Comment: And what do you want to do with the (invalid) user input at that point?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have a modal that have a form, once the user closes the modal, and open it again, all the fields still have the validations error message. I want to remove the error messages when the user closes the modal.